# UIBackgroundModes doesn't work s advertise

Tags: ios, background, audio-streaming

I red the Apple documentation about UIBackgroundModes and here is what it says :

> When this key is present, the system’s
>   audio frameworks automatically prevent
>   your application from being suspended
>   when it moves to the background. As
>   long as it is playing audio, the
>   application continues to run in the
>   background to support that audio.

However I have an app that plays an audio stream using the AVPlayer class, and it doesn't work with it. This key is suppose to be there to save us the work of implementing an Audio Session explicitely. Can anyone tell me why this is not working then ? Did anyone used it and made this work ?

Answer (score 4):

Try doing the following before playing your audio:

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code for `AVPlayer` is actually running. In my case, even though I enabled the key for `Core Location`, if I don't actually use in the code by calling `start`, the app is suspended, as if no key was defined. For this reason, I usually don't `stop` Core Location but simply let it use the least accurate option to preserve device power, yet continue to use background running mode.

Comment: In AVPlayer, I never call the pause method, therefore it shouldn't stop. It is playing as the app goes to background mode. I guess I'll just have to implement Audio Session. But still, this doc isn't telling the truth.

Comment: Also, make sure your `AVPlayer` object is not allocated in an `UIViewController` instance. Since this view may will be unloaded when the app is going background, your `AVPlayer` may be unloaded and deallocated with the `UIViewController` instance. This happens even if the app allowed to run in background. In my case, I practiced strong separation between objects to be loaded and unloaded dynamically, and the objects that should be running constantly throughout. I don't know how your app is structured, but I hope this hint can be helpful

Comment: As a matter of fact, it is implemented in the view. I don't know where and how I should implement it then...  since it's my view that starts the player. Should I put it in the app delegate ?

Comment: Yes, make an instance of a class inside `UIApplicationDelegate` as a property, which can work as a controller object for your `AVPlayer` related activities. This instance can be accessed from `UIViewController` instances using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] avplayerController]` (if you named your controller as `avplayerController`) And let your `UIViewController` instances simply `communicate` with this controller object through above mentioned selector. To receive message from this controller object, use `delegation` or `notification`.

Comment: I moved my AVPlayer instance to the AppDelegate and put it in a property as suggested. Managed to make it work, but still, it won't play in the background...  There's no release or dealoc code in the ViewController, everything is in the AppDelegate now.

Comment: One more problem that I have is warnings. I have 3 warnings now telling me "player" is not found in protocol. But I've put it in the AppDelegate. @property(nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer *player; in header file. Then @synthesize player; in .m file. But as soon as I try to get a reference that in the ViewController like this AVPlayer *playerDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] player]; I have a warning.

Comment: What about using `#import "playerClass.h"` in `yourApp_Prefix.pch` to be reachable globally? This way, even if your view controller doesn't import the class, it can still use a pointer for the object from this class. If this one doesn't work try implementing `singleton` There is an good article about this topic: http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-using-singletons/